# Calculating sum of List for any data type in java 8

Tags: java

I have a function which returns a sum of a list from specified index in the following manner:

```
myList.subList(startIndex, endIndex).stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

This works for the case of an Integer List. However is there a way to make it generic so that I can pass in a List of Doubles and I can get the sum for that as well.

This is specifically using Java 8 operations.